# Using dictionaries as switch statements in Python 2.7.3

Tags: python, switch-statement, dictionary

I like using dictionaries as a form of `switch` statment, by settings booleans as keys. Example:

```
>>> def f(a):
...      return {True: -a, a==0: 0, a > 0: a}[True]
... 
>>> f(-3)
3
>>> f(3)
3
>>> f(0)
0
```

The key `True` works as an `else`/`default` case and is only returned if no other key is evaluated to `True`. I am guessing this assumes some sort of order of evaluation for iterating the dictionary.

Now look at the following extract from the latest [release announcement from the Python team](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2012-April/1290792.html) for the newest versions of branches 2.6, 2.7, 3.1 and 3.2:

> Hash randomization causes the iteration order of dicts and sets to be
>   unpredictable and differ across Python runs. Python has never
>   guaranteed iteration order of keys in a dict or set, and applications
>   are advised to never rely on it. Historically, dict iteration order
>   has not changed very often across releases and has always remained
>   consistent between successive executions of Python. Thus, some
>   existing applications may be relying on dict or set ordering.

Does this mean that using dicts as switch calls will not be possible anymore? Or maybe I should use any other class (like `OrderedDict` or something)? Or maybe I'm completely off and it should not affect this at all?

Comment: There's no _iteration_ in your snippet - so, you're not affected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You misunderstood how this code works.

Your dictionary has only two keys: `True` and `False`. There could be multiple conflicting values for the `True` key but that gets resolved at the initialization of the dictionary.

There's no iteration for a dictionary lookup.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer made me finally understand how this code works.

Answer (score 5):

Hash randomization will not affect your application. It should only affect applications that rely on the iteration order of keys in the dictionary.

That said, I find your technique both more obscure than the simple `if..elif` chain and also less efficient (building a new dict is not cheap).

Answer (score 3):

The way you are using the dictionary to hash the condition would not be affected by the ordering. You are strictly using keys to access the dictionary and the ordering is not important to you as you are not iterating over the keys/values. So your particular usage of dictionary is immune to Python's dictionary hash randomization.

Answer (score 2):

This will probably still work, on the assumption that the dictionary is built in left-to-right order. The points about unordered iteration are about traversal once the dictionary is built, not the construction process itself, and in any event, you are indexing into it, not iterating over it.

But frankly it's not a good idea to rely on this behaviour. It's fragile, as it relies on assumed behaviour (though perhaps there's something in the spec that guarantees this) and is highly confusing, in no small part because the order of evaluation of cases is effectively right-to-left (i.e., the right-most true case wins). A much more comprehensible solution is as follows:

```
return ( a if a > 0  else
         0 if a == 0 else
        -a)
```

Answer (score 2):

First, realize that your code is more or less equivalent to:

```
def f(a):
    d = {}
    d[True] = -a
    d[a==0] = 0
    d[a>0] = a
    return d[True]
```

With that in mind, answer to your question becomes obvious.

Why do you bother with this obscure syntax instead of something simpler?
*Even* this one is more readable:

```
def f(a):
    return a if a > 0 else 0 if a == 0 else -a
```

The fact that you seem to misunderstand what your code is really doing should be a clear sign that you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very dirty code, the line with the dictionary takes minutes to read (although I work with Python for 3 years), and this will be very hard to debug. The next developer (read: yourself in half a year) will not be able to read this.

switch construct can be replaced with a dict of callbacks, if you need them:

```
 {value1: one_func, value2: another_func, value3: third_func}
```

If you need only True/False, you don't need any structure:

```
return one_func() if check else another_func()
```

In many cases, switch can be replaced with a chain of if ... return:

```
if check:
    return one_func()

return another_func() if another_check else third_func()
```

All these are much more readable and debuggable.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using iteration in your example, so your code is safe.

However, your solution is a little strange, `boolean` as a key is not very readable.

Why don't you try:

```
switch = {
   choice1: func1
   choice1: func2
   ...
}
```

and:

```
switch[variable]()
```

Answer (score 0):

That will only affect you if you're doing things like:

```
 mydict.values()[0]
```

And relying on this to always be the same value. The docs you quote say that that isn't guaranteed to happen.

However, your code has one issue that you need to consider, and that is related to short-circuiting. If you do:

```
if a == 0:
     return 0
elif a > 0:
     return a
else:
     return -a
```

Or, more succinctly (but arguably less readably) `return 0 if a == 0 else a if a > 0 else -a` , and a is 0, then `a > 0` is never evaluated (and still won't be even if you don't `return` above it). Your dictionary needs to evaluate every key you give it as a condition *every time*. The only reason to try dictionary dispatch instead of chained `if`s is efficiency, but in the case where the keys aren't constant and the entire dict precomputable, you can lose out badly.